How to transpose metric value from column to row in pivot table, looker studio
I would like to transpose the metrics from columns to rows in the pivot table on looker.
Google Sheets Pivot Tables has a similar feature, where you can select "Values as: Rows" or "Values as: Columns".
I dont see any options for doing this on the sidebar or anything similar.
